# What is a 'faculty institute'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

After looking up every definition I could find in the internet, I still don't know what **'faculty institute'** actually is. Here the link http://cet.usc.edu/new-faculty-institute/, is it an event or a seminar?

Answer (score 2):

It is a term that is specific to the University of Southern California, to describe one of their organizational structures. In other words, it is a name, which is why it has been spelled with capital letters.

One division of the University is the "Center for Excellence in Teaching" (CET). This division aims to promote high-quality teaching at the university. The teachers at a university may be called "Faculty"

The CET has created several sub-divisions, which it calls "Institutes". Each institute focuses on one aspect of teaching. For example there is an institute for promoting good leadership in teaching by fellows (ie senior academics). That is the "Faculty Fellow Leadership Institute".

A new teacher is, therefore, "New Faculty".  New faculty members may need additional support and training to achieve excellence.  So the CET has an institute for new faculty, this is the "New Faculty Institute".  It takes the form of a one year program of working lunches and workshops aimed at new professors and other teaching staff.